# HTML/CSS removing little line by link when using embedded image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

When I use an img tag inside of an a tag, these little lines at the bottom show up. I've tried several css properties to remove them and couldn't find one that did the trick. [image]

Relevant html:

```
            <a href='https://github.com/'>
                <img class='ContactLink' src='Images/Icons/GitHub.png' alt='GitHub'>
            </a>
            <a href='https://twitter.com/'>
                <img class='ContactLink' src='Images/Icons/Twitter.png' alt='Twitter'>
            </a>
            <img class='ContactLink' src='Images/Icons/Gmail.png' alt='Email'>
```

CSS:

```
.ContactLink{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide ur code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
///Add this code in CSS file
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: With this added it still shows the little dashes actually. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind I had the text-decoration: none; on the img instead of the link. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use [normalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) css or try this

```
a,a:focus,a:hover,a:active{
   text-decoration:none;
   outline-width: 0;
}
img {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to check the image files using any tool like photoshop and see if there is any transparent pixel there for that icon. Also try to keep the dimensions of all the three icon exactly same. If required edit the image accordingly.

Comment: Nothing in that pixel location when editing the files. It's gotta be something in my code because I have another website with images arranged in a similar fashion that displays the same little dashes.

Comment: Can you post the link ? So that i can investigate.

Comment: Here is a link if still curious, the text-decoration none on the a took care of it. https://jsfiddle.net/rzgt3k4y/